# asking about execute of a line

Tags: c#, c++

I wish to write a program in C# that executes line to line.

By which I mean the equivalent of C++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char c;
  puts ("Enter q to exit:");
  do {
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
  } while (c != 'q');
  return 0;
}
```

What would the equivalent in c# be?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute line to line?"

Comment: What do you mean by "Deer director"?

Comment: I have rewritten it to be usable as it sounds like a reasonable beginner question (hence previous comments invliadated)

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic c# implementation would be via the [System.Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) class.

Specifically one of 
[Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) or
[ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx)
[ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx)

Read is closest to the spirit of getchar though ReadKey is easier and safer to use. If you wish to operate line by line ratehr than character by character then ReadLine is your best bet.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
  ConsoleKeyInfo k;
  Console.WriteLine("Enter q to exit:");
  do {
    k = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(k.KeyChar);
  } while (k.KeyChar != 'q');
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Console.Read (closest to getchar()), Console.ReadKey and/or Console.ReadLine.